# Import Snapshot Failure

Tags: node

When trying to import a snapshot on a fresh install, I encounter this problem (Mac OS Mojave):

```
May 25 21:33:02 - shell.snapshots: Setting history-mode to full
tezos-node: internal error, uncaught exception:
           (Failure "Invalid argument")
           Raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 2998, characters 20-29
           Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 26, characters 8-18
           Called from file "src/bin_node/node_snapshot_command.ml", line 70, characters 10-26
           Called from file "cmdliner_term.ml", line 25, characters 19-24
           Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 25, characters 27-34
           Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 116, characters 32-39
```

Comment: This issue was reported on Mac OS only. It was fixed and should be in mainnet soon. In the meantime, you can cherry-pick that commit https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/commit/4a275930d3ad3e6b2f3536aa6a76f2b6de59ef2f?merge_request_iid=1084

Comment: @vect0r please convert your comment into an answer so we can flag this question as satisfactory answered. thx

Comment: The fix was merged to mainnet branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This merge into the [mainnet](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/commit/797d56105d786b50fbc49f531280810b575485a9) should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Importing a snapshot is still broken in Mac OS.

tezos-node: internal error, uncaught exception:
(Failure "Invalid argument")
Raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 2998, characters 20-29
Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 26, characters 8-18
Called from file "src/bin_node/node_snapshot_command.ml", line 70, characters 10-26
Called from file "cmdliner_term.ml", line 25, characters 19-24
Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 25, characters 27-34
Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 116, characters 32-39